# $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $|f(z)|=1$ on $|z|=1$, show $f$ is rational.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I believe $f$ should be in the form of finite product of Blacshke factors and reciprocals. I have no idea how to show number of zeros or poles are finite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since $f(\mathbb{T})\subseteq\mathbb{T}$, if it has infinitely many zeroes or poles there would be an accumulation point somewhere inside the unit disc by reflection principle.  Now what happens at that accumulation point?

Alternatively, immediately appeal to reflection principle to extend $f$ as a holomorphic map $S^2\to S^2$, so $f$ must be rational.

Comment: But $f$ is defined in whole complex plane. It can happen that it has infinitely many  zeros. I am not sure how to make them accumulate and to contradict this by identity theorem. Moreover, identity theorem is applied on zeros of holomorphic functions. I am not sure if it can be applied to zeros of meromorphic functions.

Comment: That is why I think $|f(z)|=1$ on $|z|=1$ could be crucial but I have no idea.

Comment: Use the reflection principle to map pole z to zero $\bar{z}^{-1}$ as in isometry of unit disc.  (I thought you know that already since you know Blaschke products.)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. But I am not sure what reflection principle you are referring to.

Comment: I'm referring to $f\colon\bar{\mathbb{D}}\to S^2$ continuous and meromorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, $f(\mathbb{T})\subseteq\mathbb{T}$ implies the extension $f(z)=1/\overline{f(1/\bar{z})}$ is a holomorphic extension $S^2\to S^2$.

Comment: Oops, sorry the codomain should be $S^2$.  The full assumption is that $f$ is a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces $\mathbb{D}\to S^2$ or equivalently meromorphic function on $\mathbb{D}$, continuous up to the boundary and mapping the boundary (unit circle) $\mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: Then I need to check this case of reflection principle seems not seen in  textbook.

Comment: That is not difficult to check.  The most obvious way is to use weakly-conformal (i.e. same as conformal except you allow zero derivative) + orientation-preserving = holomorphic to get it on all points outside $\mathbb{T}$, and for points in $\mathbb{T}$ since they are mapped to $\mathbb{T}$ there is a nbhd where $f$ has no zeroes or poles, hence Morera applies.

Comment: But after showing number of zeros and poles are finite, how can I make it a rational functions? And my guess is about Blacshke factors, how do I know if those zeros or poles are inside the unit circle? Is my guess correct actually?

Comment: Recall a finite-degree holomorphic map $S^2\to S^2$ is a rational function (the ratio $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{R(z)}$, where $R(z)$ is a rational function having the same zeros and poles (counted with multiplicities), has only removable singularities at those zeros and poles.  Hence $g$ is a holomorphic map $S^2\to\mathbb{C}$ which is constant by open mapping theorem).  The poles could be inside the unit disc, in other words, $f$ is a ratio of two finite Blaschke products.

Comment: $f$ and $R$ shall be defined on $\mathbb{C}$, why g can be defined on $\{\infty\}$?

Comment: $f$ as given is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ only, we cannot ensure whether it would be meromorphic/ holomorphic/ essential singularity at $\{\infty\}$. For the first 2 cases, $f$ is rational. However, how we can remove the possibility that f is having a essential singularity at $\infty$?

Comment: Recall we extended that to $S^2-\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ using (the chart $1/z$ and) $1/\overline{f(1/\bar{z}))}$ in reflection principle.  So that defines a holomorphic map $S^2\to S^2$, i.e., no essential singularity can occur at $\infty$ because it doesn't occur at $0$.

Comment: By identity theorem, the reflected new function by extension from a disc is the same as the old function on the whole $\mathbb{C}$. Plus, it is defined at $\infty$ as $g(\infty)=1/ \bar{f(0)}$. An your argument can go on. I am still not used to meromorphic functions and $1/z$ technique. Thank you very much!

Comment: But $f$ is not real-valued on the circle, can we still reflect it?

Comment: You can since $f$ is $\mathbb{T}$-valued on $\mathbb{T}$, and reflection across $\mathbb{T}$ is the inversion (take the point on the ray $0w$ whose distance from $0$ is the reciprocal of the distance between 0 and $w$.), i.e. $w\mapsto 1/\bar{w}$ (you can check this is what you get if you conjugate by the identification of the disc with upper half space).

Answer (score 0):

Let $g\left(z\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$. Then, $g$
has exactly the same properties as $f$. The same is true for the reciprocals of $f$ and $g$.

With that in mind, we turn our attention to $f$ as a function on the Riemann sphere, $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. Now, suppose $f$ has infinitely many poles. Thus, the set $P_{f}$ of poles of $f$ in  $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is infinite. Since the Riemann sphere is a compact Riemann surface, compactness guarantees that $P_{f}$ has an accumulation point $w$ in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. If $w$ is not in the open unit disk, then its reciprocal $v$ *will* be in the open unit disk, and vice versa. Thus, we have that one of $f$ or $g$ has an accumulation point of poles in $\mathbb{D}$, and thus, that one of the reciprocals of $f$ and $g$ must have an accumulation point of zeroes in the closure of $\mathbb{D}$. However, since both of these functions have unit magnitude on the unit circle, the accumulation point must lie inside $\mathbb{D}$. Thus, by the identity theorem, since one of $f$ and $g$'s reciprocals has an accumulation point of zeroes in its domain, it must be a constant. By construction, this then forces both $f$ and $g$ to be constant on the Riemann circle, which contradicts the assumption that $f$ had infinitely many poles.

Repeating this argument with the reciprocals of $f$ and $g$ in place of $f$ and $g$ then gives the corresponding result about the zeroes of $f$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: I would like to ask some further questions. If $f$ has finite number of zeros, $z_1,..,z_k$ and poles $p_1,..,p_j$, are these zeros and poles necessarily in the unit circle? Moreover, is it directly followed that $f(z)=\product \frac{z-z_m}{z-p_n}\frac{1-\bar{z_m}z}{1-\bar{p_n}z}$ ?

Comment: I take it by, "in the unit circle" you mean "enclosed by the unit circle". To that, the answer is probably yes, but I'm not sure how to show it. 

The answer to your second question, I believe, is "no": $f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{z}$ satisfies the given hypothesis (both yours, and the problem's) and has no Blaschke product representation.

Comment: To be very exact, it means they are in $\{|z|<1\}$. Because this is the only way to make my Blacshke factor guess make sense.

Comment: I should clarify, I mean It shall be a product of Blacshke factors divided by a product of Blacshke factors. Hence, $1/z$ does not contradict. I guess so because Blacshke factors seems to be the only way to make $|f(z)|=1$ on $|z|=1$ true.